# How can I use target address to get sum of a range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range, target

I have target.address (or just target) from a worksheet_change sub. I'd like to use the row from target.address and a range of columns (H:W), and get a sum of that range. So, for instance, if I have $100 in H10 and I add $50 in J10, I'd like to get the sum of $150 since my target.address row is 10 and I'm within my desired column range H:W.

Comment: Will `Target` always be a single-cell range?

Comment: Since Target is a range object, you can use the Row property to determine your row to Sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Intersect` and `EntireRow` to figure out which cells to sum.  I would give them to `Application.Sum` to do the math.  Another call to `Intersect` will let you know if the changed cell is in the "boxed" area.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sum As Double
    Dim rng_match As Range

    Set rng_match = Range("H:W")

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, rng_match) Is Nothing Then
            sum = Application.sum(Intersect(Target.EntireRow, rng_match))
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit:** added a check on `Target.Cells.Count` per @Tim Williams to ensure that the sum is not affected by a multi-cell edit.  The `Else` would need to address what to do next if this is an issue.

Comment: If the user were to change >1 cell then this could return misleading results by summing multiple rows.

Comment: Good point, @TimWilliams.  I read your comment above and assumed the answer was "Yes".  I guess really he has no control over how many cells are changed... so it's worth checking.  See edit.